# how to refactor code where only the variables are different

Tags: java, refactoring

hi all: I am working on two java programs where literally the only difference between the two are a beginning statement defining a 2-dimensional array. i have shortened the code substantially in the below example:

```
public class Qwerty {
    /** this is what needs to be replaced */
    private static char master[][] = {
        QwertyKbd.lIndex,
        QwertyKbd.lMiddle,
        QwertyKbd.lRing,
        QwertyKbd.lPinky,
            /** and so forth in this fashion */
    };

    public static int[] analyze(String file) {
    }

    public static void split(char c) {
    }
}
```

and the second class here:

```
 public class Dvorak{
        /** this is what needs to be replaced */
        private static char master[][] = {
            /** various definitions, eliminated for conciseness */
        };

        public static int[] analyze(String file) {
            /** this is the same*/
        }

        public static void split(char c) {
            /** this is the same*/
        }
    }
```

the question is how can i refactor to get one class where the only difference is the 'master' 2-d array? hook methods etc. would be stupid here. because there's nothing that the program DOES that needs to be modified. what do you think?

Comment: @minitech: inheritance with all static fields and methods? Without improving his classes, inheritance won't do a thing. To the original poster: get rid of your statics, use instance fields and methods and please read some introductory tutorials that go into use of classes and methods.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Ah, I missed that they were `static` at all. Sorry :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't do that if your classes are in diffent projects 
But if they are parts of an project, you could create an abstract class, or superclass for all of your classes: Qwerty, Dvorak...
For example, you create an abstract

```
public class CustomAbstract{
    protected char master[][];
    public int[] analyze(String file){return null;};
    public void split(char c){};
}
```

Then in your classes, you extends this abstract class

```
public class Qwerty extends CustomAbstract{
    public Qwerty(){
        //master = ...;
    }
    //your code
}
```

When you refactor the master field in CustomAbstract, all of master in other classes are refactored, too.

The problem of above code is that you couldnt use static field master, eventhough static method analyze, etc. May be you need all of methods and fields in your classes are static, you could use single skeleton pattern. In each class, you create a static method like that

```
public class Qwerty extends CustomAbstract{
    //your code
    static Qwerty instance = new Qwerty();
    public static Qwerty getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then instead of using Qwerty.analyze(String), you can use Qwerty.getInstance().analyze(String)
Hope this help.

Comment: Why couldn't you do it if the classes were in separate projects? Why do you need an abstract class?

Comment: Actually, you could do that if the IDE you using support!!!. Refactoring is not replacing. If you replace, the only thing needed is that all of classes have fields with the same name "master", but if you refactor, all of classes must have the same context, e.g. all of classes have the same field "master" inherits from a superclass/abstract class

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is a classic case for inheritance. The real purpose of inheritance is code reuse, which is exactly what you're getting at here. I'd make all the methods non-static and do an "Extract Superclass" on them, pulling `analyze()` and `split()` into the abstract class, and adding an abstract `getMaster()` or some such, which each class would override to return the appropriate values.

The worse alternative--for several reasons, but primarily because it leaves you in "static land", which is a terrible place to be--would be to simply move `analyze()` and `split()` into some third class which is a place to house your "shared" utility methods like these.

Comment: +1 - Java is an OO language, and you (@franklin) need to start *thinking* in terms of objects.  The `static` keyword should be used sparingly ...